# Receiving Ethernet frames from an UDP port

Tags: c, linux, udp, ethernet

I need to listen on multiple UDP ports and process received datagrams as Ethernet frames. I cannot think of any other solution than creating a SOCK_RAW socket to receive ethernet frames, check if what I received is an UDP datagram and then extract the datagram to identify the UDP port.

Is there a better way? Is there some kind of socket that would let me receive UDP datagrams on a specific port and still access the whole Ethernet frame?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [pcap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) library. It's not hard and it's portable between wide area of systems. You can simply filter and capture what you want.

> libpcap and WinPcap provide the packet-capture and filtering engines
>   of many open source and commercial network tools, including protocol
>   analyzers (packet sniffers), network monitors, network intrusion
>   detection systems, traffic-generators and network-testers.

Another suggestions is [libcrafter](http://code.google.com/p/libcrafter/) which is a high-level packet creator and decoder. Though it's C++ only.

Comment: This is the answer you're looking for.  You can't access the frame without writing a device driver, since the NIC deals with all the header information and then passes the packet up to the kernel (i.e. the kernel never even sees the header I don't think!).  But you don't actually need the header to get hte UDP port, since this is located in the UDP packet since the port actually distinguishes which program the packet should be sent to.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is supported on your platform, but try:

```
    int s=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_PACKET,htons(ETH_P_ALL));
```

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Ethernet-HOWTO-2.html